# GWT - setting Canvas size when not visible

Tags: html, gwt, canvas

I have a canvas in a hidden panel. It is created before the panel is made visible. The problem I'd like to set its DOM width to 100% but I have a problem with the setCoordinateSpaceWidth then as I cannot get the canvas dimension via getOffsetWidth as the canvas is not visible. I don't even think I can add a resizeevent to Canvas nor is there a VisibleEvent. Would appreciate if anybody had an idea as to how to circumvent the problem?

Cheers,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

(One potential solution below, not just a "me too". Keep reading)

Similar problem here.
Canvas in a tab on a TabLayoutPanel.
Some controls on a second tab to manipulate the canvas.
Drawing fails because canvas reports a 0 width.

Either a reliable way to get the canvas (or it's container element) width or a VisibleEvent would be perfect.

My solution was to add a selectionHandler to the tab panel.
When my canvas' panel becomes visible, I use scheduleDeferred to call method that enables drawing on the canvas and forces a redraw. When a tab other than my canvas is selected, I disable drawing on my canvas.

Won't work for everyone, but may give you an idea!